# What is the proper name of the 3D shape of a teardrop?

Tags: geometry, terminology

A circle is 2D.

A sphere is a 3D circle.

A "teardrop" 2D shape (bottom half circle, top-half kindof diamond shape) probably has a name (I don't know - someone suggested squircle which I love - because it's half square, half circle...). Maybe a lachrymaform? Maybe a symmetrical airfoil?

Anyhow - what's the name of a 3D one of these? bottom-half sphere, with the top half terminating in a sharp point?

Comment: I'm afraid squircle is already taken (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle). I think teardrop is probably the best name for it already.

Comment: the name of teardrop curve is also taken ([ref](http://www.2dcurves.com/higher/highert.html))

Comment: I call the 3D version an upside-down ice cream cone.

Comment: Orientation should not matter for a general 3D shape.  This is a cone+sphere.  Call it an ice cream cone if you like.

Comment: teardrop is the 2D shape.  The actual shape of the real-world physical one (raindrop) bears no resemblance to the shape I'm trying to name (real droplets are flattened on the bottom and with a curved dome on top, they actually resemble a hamburger bun or a kidney bean - not a teardrop shape).

So yeah.  

"Sphere" is the shape-name for a "3D circle".

I beginning to think there is *no* name for a 3D Teardrop ?

Comment: Well, you keep calling it a "3D teardrop" and we all know what you're talking about, so I respectfully suggest that there is a name and you're using it.